# Any Windows alternative to Unix utility Ethtool for autonegotiation of ethernet?

Tags: linux, windows, ethernet

I have to implement the windows equivalent of the following :

```
for iface in `ifconfig -a | sed 's/[ \t].*//;/^$/d'`;
do echo \"ethtool back on $iface\";
ethtool -s $iface  autoneg on ;
done
```

How can this be done in Windows, through command line?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of getting and setting speed/duplex/autonegotiation on single named interface using PowerShell:

```
PS> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V      26 Disconnected E8-6A-64-3B-28-1A          0 bps
Wi-Fi                     Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265          10 Up           18-1D-EA-B4-7E-0E       300 Mbps

PS> Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name Ethernet -DisplayName "Speed & Duplex" | fl DisplayName, DisplayValue, ValidDisplayValues,Name

DisplayName        : Speed & Duplex
DisplayValue       : Auto Negotiation
ValidDisplayValues : {Auto Negotiation, 10 Mbps Half Duplex, 10 Mbps Full Duplex, 100 Mbps Half Duplex...}
Name               : Ethernet

PS> Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name Ethernet -DisplayName "Speed & Duplex" -DisplayValue "100 Mbps Half Duplex"

PS> Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name Ethernet -DisplayName "Speed & Duplex" | fl DisplayName, DisplayValue

DisplayName  : Speed & Duplex
DisplayValue : 100 Mbps Half Duplex
```

Parameterizing and adding a loop to iterate over all the interfaces, I will leave that task to you.